# How to make a Postman collection wait in between calls

Tags: javascript, api, postman

I have a list of API services that my postman collection executes, however it is causing a problem because they are executing too fast.

Does anyone know how I can make it wait in between the calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a collection of your APIs in postman and add delay on your postman runner.

[image]

Comment: thanks that worked when using postman. I am also running these tests in web storm do you know how I would add the delay to the file?

Answer (score 1):

If you are executing tests through command line runner (Newman), you can use:

`--delay-request
Specify the extent of delay between requests (milliseconds).`

For further information refer:
https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman#command-line-options